# Suggestions for Authentication of Mac Catalyst app in MAUI

Tags: .net, macos, authentication, maui, mac-catalyst

I am trying to migrate our Xamarin.Mac app to MAUI and am looking for suggestions for Authentication as MSAL does not support Catalyst

Trying to use MSAL fails to compile for Mac Catalyst

Answer (score 0):

Seems most people are borrowing from Auth0 a bit in their implementation since the major issue with Authentication on Mac Catalyst with .NET MAUI is mostly surrounding the secure access of Mac OS's keystore. I've sucessfully gotten this example to run and have started adopting it for my own needs.

https://github.com/coding-flamingo/MAUI-MAC-Auth/blob/main/MAUIMACAuth/Services/AuthenticationService.cs